# Spark - "sbt package" - "value $ is not a member of StringContext" - Missing Scala plugin?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, apache-spark-sql

When running "sbt package" from the command line for a small Spark Scala application, I'm getting the "value $ is not a member of StringContext" compilation error on the following line of code:

```
val joined = ordered.join(empLogins, $"login" === $"username", "inner")
  .orderBy($"count".desc)
  .select("login", "count")
```

Intellij 13.1 is giving me the same error message. The same .scala source code gets compiled without any issue in Eclipse 4.4.2. And also it works well with maven in a separate maven project from the command line.

It looks like sbt doesn't recognize the $ sign because I'm missing some plugin in my project/plugins.sbt file or some setting in my build.sbt file.

Are you familiar with this issue? Any pointers will be appreciated. I can provide build.sbt and/or project/plugins.sbt if needed be.

Comment: Probably it would help if you would describe what do you think `$` does. Do you have a special import? Do you use plugins? I know you already mentioned plugins, but if you already suspect, why did you not share the used plugins?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to make sure you [`import sqlContext.implicits._`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$)

This gets you `implicit class StringToColumn extends AnyRef`

Which is commented as:

> Converts $"col name" into an Column.

Comment: I did like this still giving error ...any suggestion please i am using scala 2.11

 val resultDf = accumulated_results_df.as("a").join(computed_df.as("c"), 
                             ( $"a.company_id" === $"c.company_id" ) && ( $"c.min_dd" > $"a.max_dd" )  , "left")

Error :

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'company_id' is ambiguous, could be: a.company_id, c.company_id.;

Comment: @BdLearner The error stats the problem - you are joining where you have ambiguous columns

Answer (score 16):

## In Spark 2.0+

**$-notation for columns** can be used by importing implicit on `SparkSession` object (`spark`)

```
val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
        .master("local")
        .appName("App name")
        .getOrCreate;

import spark.implicits._
```

then your code with $ notation

```
val joined = ordered.join(empLogins, $"login" === $"username", "inner")
  .orderBy($"count".desc)
  .select("login", "count")
```

Answer (score 4):

Great answer guys, if resolving import is a concern, then will this work

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, SQLContext}
val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").getOrCreate()
val dataDf = ...

import ss.sqlContext.implicits._
dataDf.filter(not($"column_name1" === "condition"))
```

Comment: No need to use `sqlContext` in Spark 2.x, `SparkSession` is enough.