# Create a new column based on date checking

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have two dataframes in Scala:

```
df1 =

ID  Field1
1   AAA
2   BBB
4   CCC
```

and

```
df2 =

PK  start_date_time
1   2016-10-11 11:55:23
2   2016-10-12 12:25:00
3   2016-10-12 16:20:00
```

I also have a variable `start_date` with the format `yyyy-MM-dd` equal to `2016-10-11`.

I need to create a new column `check` in `df1` based on the following condition: `If PK is equal to ID AND the year, month and day of start_date_time are equal to start_date, then check is equal to 1, otherwise 0`.

The result should be this one:

```
df1 =

ID  Field1  check
1   AAA     1
2   BBB     0
4   CCC     0
```

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701949/compare-dates-in-dataframes?noredirect=1#comment70599988_41701949) I had two dataframes and it was suggested to use joining and filtering. However, in this case it won't work. My initial idea was to use `udf`, but not sure how to make it working for this case.

Comment: Specify that you're using spark. There are no default dataframes in Scala that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `join` and `withColumn` for this case. i.e. firstly join with `df2` on ID column and then use `when.otherwise` syntax to modify the check column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

val df2_date = df2.withColumn("date", to_date(df2("start_date_time"))).withColumn("check", lit(1)).select($"PK".as("ID"), $"date", $"check")

df1.join(df2_date, Seq("ID"), "left").withColumn("check", when($"date" === "2016-10-11", $"check").otherwise(0)).drop("date").show

+---+------+-----+
| ID|Field1|check|
+---+------+-----+
|  1|   AAA|    1|
|  2|   BBB|    0|
|  4|   CCC|    0|
+---+------+-----+
```

---

Or another option, firstly filter on `df2`, and then join it back with `df1` on `ID` column:

```
val df2_date = (df2.withColumn("date", to_date(df2("start_date_time"))).
                    filter($"date" === "2016-10-11").
                    withColumn("check", lit(1)).
                    select($"PK".as("ID"), $"date", $"check"))

df1.join(df2_date, Seq("ID"), "left").drop("date").na.fill(0).show

+---+------+-----+
| ID|Field1|check|
+---+------+-----+
|  1|   AAA|    1|
|  2|   BBB|    0|
|  4|   CCC|    0|
+---+------+-----+
```

---

In case you have a date like `2016-OCT-11`, you can convert it sql Date for comparison as follows:

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")
val parsed = format.parse("2016-OCT-11")
val date = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime())
// date: java.sql.Date = 2016-10-11
```

Comment: Does `to_date` automatically convert the values in `start_date_time` to `yyyy-MM-dd`? What if I have `yyyy-MMM-dd` in `start_date`? How then `start_date_time` will be compared to `start_date`?

Comment: In that case, you should be able to use `start_date_time` directly without convert it using `to_date`.

Comment: I mean, let's say `start_date_time` is equal to `2016-10-11 11:55:23` and it should be compared to `start_date` equal to `2016-OCT-11` (`yyyy-MMM-dd`). So, where do I define the formatting of `start_date_time`?

Comment: I cannot compile symbols `$`. Which library should I import? I am using Spark 1.6.2.

Comment: `$` is spark column syntax, not from other libraries. Try `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit`.

Comment: It still says `error: value $ is not a member of StringContext`

Comment: what spark version are you using? I am not getting error message with spark 2.0.2

Comment: I am using Spark 1.6.2 and I cannot switch to Spark 2 as it's the production environment.

Comment: You can try split the chained transformation commands above and use `dfxx("xxx")` syntax to replace `$"xxx"` here `dfxx` is the data frame name and `xxx` is the column name. Not sure if that will solve the problem though. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445476/spark-sbt-package-value-is-not-a-member-of-stringcontext-missing-sca)

Comment: Try `import sqlContext.implicits._`

Comment: import sqlContext.implicits._ solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I published a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708265/join-two-dataframes-by-id
If you are interested, you may take a look.