# Defining a DataTypes.DateType

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark

I am trying to learn Spark. I have a `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` which I am reading in as a `DataFrame`. And then I am trying to filter it using a condition on a column:

```
val resultDataFrame = dataFrame.filter(col("DATECOL") >= date)
```

The `DATECOL` is being read as `DataTypes.DateType`in to the DataFrame. `date` is a variable that I have to hardcode.

What I am trying to figure out is how can I define `date` i.e. how can I create an instance of `DataTypes.DateType` or convert to it from a `String` or so, so that I can run the above expression. I tried using a `String` and it does not give an error, but it returns with no results where it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it a *java.sql.Date*:

```
val df = Seq(("2016-10-10", 2), ("2017-02-02", 10)).toDF("DATECOL", "value")

val df1 = df.withColumn("DATECOL", to_date($"DATECOL"))
// df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DATECOL: date, value: int]

df1.show
+----------+-----+
|   DATECOL|value|
+----------+-----+
|2016-10-10|    2|
|2017-02-02|   10|
+----------+-----+

val date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2016-11-01")
// date: java.sql.Date = 2016-11-01

df1.filter($"DATECOL" > date).show
+----------+-----+
|   DATECOL|value|
+----------+-----+
|2017-02-02|   10|
+----------+-----+
```

Comment: hold on, a `String` works as well! I think I made a mistake looking at the results earlier.

Comment: Hmm. A string of standard format does work, this will be just in case you have some [peculiar case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703517/create-a-new-column-based-on-date-checking).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean [Peculiar case]? Is using a String not a "recommended" way to go in this case?

Comment: No, I mean if some times you have non standard format string that spark doesn't understand, such as `2016-OCT-12`. But since you are hard coding here, it is actually irrelevant.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks, this helps!